# How to print specific value in a dictionary without the brackets based on user choice

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I am learning python and I have the following scenario: Create a data structure that associates two values. Then retrieve the specific data without using an if/else statement. This is what I came up with.

```
def menu():
 print("1. fruit 1")
 print("2. fruit 2")
 print("3. fruit 3")

fruits = {
  1: ["Fruit 1", "Message", "Healthy"],
  2: ["Fruit 2", "Message", "Unhealthy"],
  3: ["Fruit 3", "Message", "Healthy"]
 }
 
 menu()
 option = int(input("Choose your fruit: ")
 print(fruits.get(option))
```

This works but it prints out the brackets and quotation marks. How do I make it prettier? I've seen other examples but it usually only deals with a simple one line dictionary without user input. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
print(', '.join(fruits.get(option, ['Invalid fruit'])))
```

This will give a comma-separated list of the values, and an error message if the fruit doesn't exist. For example in a loop:

```
fruits = {
  1: ["Fruit 1", "Message", "Healthy"],
  2: ["Fruit 2", "Message", "Unhealthy"],
  3: ["Fruit 3", "Message", "Healthy"]
 }

for option in range(5):
    print(', '.join(fruits.get(option, ['Invalid fruit'])))
```

Output:

```
Invalid fruit
Fruit 1, Message, Healthy
Fruit 2, Message, Unhealthy
Fruit 3, Message, Healthy
Invalid fruit
```

Comment: Thank you much. This is what I was looking for. I can play around with the formatting. Out of curiosity, why did you add Invalid fruit?

Comment: @user2816227 I put that in because you don't have a check in your code that the input is valid (i.e. one of 1, 2 or 3). You can leave it out if you don't want it.

Comment: So it does work. But I need it to print out specifically an input from the user. So if the user chooses Fruit 1, It should only print out the fruit 1 message. But I have a good starting to point now.

Comment: @user2816227 yes, you would still use your input code and you can either add code to check for a valid input or use a default value for the get as I did in the answer. I just put a loop in the answer to show what the output would be for 5 different input values (0,1,2,3,4).

Comment: Thank you so much. I changed it to the following: print('\n'.join(breedsDict.get(option)))

Answer (score 1):

Use format:

```py
option = int(input("Choose your fruit: "))
fruit = fruits.get(option)
if fruit is not None:
    print(f"{fruit[0]}, {fruit[1]}, {fruit[2]}")
```

Comment: That prints out the entire dictionary and it still has all the brackets.

Comment: @user2816227  
`1. fruit 1`   
`2. fruit 2`  
`3. fruit 3`
`Choose your fruit: 1`
`Fruit 1, Message, Healthy`
Here is my test. I don't see brackets.

Comment: I don't know why but mine prints everything.